# Check whether iptables or nftables are in use

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter, nftables

Given a host that is in an unknown state of configuration, I would like to know if there is an effective way of non-interactively determining if the firewall rule set in place is managed by `iptables` or `nftables`.

Sounds pretty simple and I've given this quite a bit of thought, but haven't come back with a meaningful answer to put on a script...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variant of this problem [was addressed recently in Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71305), so it’s worth looking at what was done there. (The variant is whether to use `iptables-legacy` or `iptables-nft` and their IPv6 variants to drive the host’s rules.)

The approach taken in Kubernetes is [to look at the number of lines output by the respective “save” commands](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ffe93b3979486feb41a0f85191bdd189cbd56ccc/build/debian-iptables/iptables-wrapper), `iptables-legacy-save` and `iptables-nft-save` (and their IPv6 variants). If the former produces ten lines or more of output, or produces more output than the latter, then it’s assumed that `iptables-legacy` should be used; otherwise, that `iptables-nft` should be used.

In your case, the decision tree could be as follows:

- if `iptables` isn’t installed, use `nft`;
- if `nft` isn’t installed, use `iptables`;
- if `iptables-save` doesn’t produce any rule-defining output, use `nft`;
- if `nft list tables` and `nft list ruleset` don’t produce any output, use `iptables`.

If `iptables-save` and `nft list ...` both produce output, and `iptables` isn’t `iptables-nft`, I’m not sure an automated process can decide.

Comment: Interesting. What I am finding is that `iptables-save`, `iptables-legacy-save` and `iptables-nft-save` all return null output (on debian) if an nft ruleset is defined. If a rule is defined using `iptables-nft`, then the output of `iptables-nft-save` returns data reflecting the change, but not the entirety of the nft ruleset (not necessarily an issue in this particular case), yet the nft ruleset is updated to contain the change added with `iptables-nft`. I think I can work out  a solution from this information, thank you.

Comment: What happens if both appear to work?

Comment: @user3728501 both what? If both `-save` variants appear to work, see the “If” part at the end of the second paragraph; if you’re referring to something else, see the last paragraph.

Comment: All of the above command appear to be working?

Comment: @user3728501 so you end up falling off the end of the decision tree, and the last part applies: “I’m not sure an automated process can decide.”

Comment: seems like a pointless answer

Comment: @user3728501 I’ll give you a refund. Sometimes the answer is that there is no answer; or in your case, that I’d need more info. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Fair enough - I agree sometimes there is no good answer

Comment: Or comparing `md5sum $(which iptables-nft)` which gives `018cd4bcdaad2cc4310f7e19da2a8a99  /usr/sbin/iptables-nft` to `md5sum $(which iptables)` which gives `018cd4bcdaad2cc4310f7e19da2a8a99  /usr/sbin/iptables`. Same checksums. Thus `nftables` is in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly tell whether `iptables` or `nftables` is in use by looking at the output of `iptables -V`.  Not 100% optimal as it still requires a little output parsing, but quite straight forward.

Redhat has a [blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/08/18/iptables-the-two-variants-and-their-relationship-with-nftables) from 2020-08 with guidance on this that also applies to Ubuntu.

> The two variants of the `iptables` command are:
>
> - `legacy`: Often referred to as `iptables-legacy`.
> - `nf_tables`: Often referred to as `iptables-nft`.
>
> The newer `iptables-nft` command provides a bridge to the nftables
> kernel API and infrastructure.

> You can find out which variant is in
> use by looking up the iptables version.

### Ubuntu 22.04 (nftables)

> For `iptables-nft`, the variant
> will be shown in parentheses after the version number, denoted as
> nf_tables:

```
# iptables -V
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
```

### Ubuntu 20.04 (iptables)

> For `iptables-legacy`, the variant will either be absent, or it will show legacy in parentheses:

```
# iptables -V
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy)
```

## Testing

So a simple test with grep to determine if we are nftables or not would be:

```bash
iptables -V | grep -E ' \(nf_tables\) *$'
```

...it is possible in the future that `iptables` is no longer distributed by default and so a more future-proof test would look something like:

```bash
if command -v iptables; then
    if iptables -V | grep -E ' \(nf_tables\) *$'; then
        echo "nft"
    else
        echo "iptables"
    fi
elif command -v nft; then
    echo "nft";
fi
```